# How to install, mysql-workbench in CentOS6?

Tags: centos, mysql, mysql-workbench

well.

How to install mysql-workbench in CentOS6 i686?

first, su -c 'yum install mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.42-1fc15.i686.rpm'

but

```
    --> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.42-1fc15.i686 (/mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.42-1fc15.i686)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.15)
Error: Package: mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.42-1fc15.i686 (/mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.42-1fc15.i686)
           Requires: libpython2.7.so.1.0
Error: Package: mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.42-1fc15.i686 (/mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.42-1fc15.i686)
           Requires: libctemplate.so.0
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

any idea? thanks

Comment: Make sure that you install build-essential. See if that will let you install workbench.

Comment: mm not work, yum install build-essential, and > "No package build-essential available." in the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've downloaded the Fedora package. Go back and download the RHEL6 package.